# Where to add Dropout in CNN-LSTM?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, dropout

I am creating a CNN-LSTM model to forecast sequential simulation data. At the moment I am not sure what the best place is to use Dropout in a CNN-LSTM architecture. Is it between the CNN and LSTM layer or after the LSTM layer?

At this [site](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/09/dropout-convolutional-networks.html) they mention that dropout is less effective at CNN layers:

> dropout is generally less effective at regularizing convolutional
> layers.
>
> The reason? Since convolutional layers have few parameters, they need
> less regularization to begin with. Furthermore, because of the spatial
> relationships encoded in feature maps, activations can become highly
> correlated.

And in this post [Where should I place dropout layers in a neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240305/where-should-i-place-dropout-layers-in-a-neural-network) :

> We must not use dropout layer after convolutional layer as we slide
> the filter over the width and height of the input image we produce a
> 2-dimensional activation map that gives the responses of that filter
> at every spatial position.

In this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Place-of-dropout-in-RNNs-with-respect-to-the-LSTM-layer_fig1_308849574) they conclude:

> It seems like dropout is best close to the inputs and outputs of the
> network.

So, I am not sure what the best place is to add dropout in a CNN-LSTM architecture but I assume that it is after the LSTM layer, right?